# Integral bounds

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Given an integral like the following:

$\int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^n dx$ and the substitution like $x=\sin^2 \theta$

What would the limits be?

I went to proceed like so:
$1=\sin^2 \theta$ or $\cos^2 \theta = 0$ so $\theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$
Also, for the lower bound: $0=\sin^2 \theta$ or $\theta = \frac{n\pi}{2}$.

How do I know choose the bounds?

Comment: I would recommend $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: So do you know what the limit is? Is the limit also part of your question?

Answer (score 3):

By [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function),
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)^2}{\Gamma(2n+2)} = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}.\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ may be checked by integration by parts, no need of trigonometric substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean-value theorem we have
$$
0 \leq \int_{x=0}^{1} x^{n}(1-x)^{n} \leq \sup_{t \in ]0,1[}t^{n}(1-t)^{n} \to 0.
$$